# Is Google Adsense works with Angular SPA Web applications?

Tags: angular, google-ads-api, adsense

I have an Angular SPA web application,  register my site to Adsense they approved in 1 day later I inject the codes for showing ads. And other day ads started to shown. 1 hour later I started to see little income. But then income stopped but ads still in my site. Reports on Adsense counts the view but there is no income. Its like this last 3 weeks.

Is there anyone have experience with Adsense and Angular, because I feel like Adsense doesn't work with angular.

Comment: Not sure but if you use Angular you might try SSR and then you should be safe. https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: Thanks man, im not sure about is SSR must have on angular that's why im looking for more answers.